# Is there a way to format decimal point numbers while using PrintWriter, without using "Format" function in Java?

Tags: java, formatting, format, filewriter, printwriter

I am writing out data to a file for my Java simulation. My code looks like this:

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("data/test.dat", true));)
      {
        out.print(DecimalPointData);
        out.print("\t");
        out.print(OtherData);
        out.print("\n");            
        } catch (IOException {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This prints out data like this:

```
  -1.0749999955296516   0.0
  -1.0919999964535236   0.0
  -1.0749999955296516   0.0
  -0.5339999794960022   0.0
```

I am aware of the fact that data in java can be formatted using .format, i.e., if I can just say

```
out.format("%.3f%n",DecimalPointData);
```

instead of

```
out.print(DecimalPointData);
```

But I do not want to use this in my code, because when I write to the file, the columns look disoriented, my file data looks ends up looking like this:

```
-1.075
      0.0
-1.092
      0.0
-1.075
      0.0
```

Is there anything else I need to know while formatting? or Is there another way to format decimal point numbers with the use of "Format" function in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single format to write a line

```
out.format("%.3f %.1f%n",DecimalPointData, OtherData);
```

EDIT:
If you want to add a TAB in your output, use the below format string

```
out.format("%.3f\t%.1f%n",DecimalPointData, OtherData);
```

Comment: Works perfect thanks, and in case I had a third set of data I would just change that to "%.3f %.1f %.1f%n"?

Comment: Right answer, but it lacks the tab character `\t` that was in the question.

Comment: @neo-su: yes, you can add more data as required. You use the format string to control how you want the data to be formatted

Comment: Another question if you don't mind, how do I print a blank line after all the numbers have been printed. I know I can print a blank line just by saying out.print("\n") but this would print blank lines between each row.

Comment: add the line out.print("\n"); after you have printed all your data

Comment: Thanks, I finally figured out the problem. It had something to do with my main program.

Answer (score 0):

From [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html):

> The %n is a platform-independent newline character.

Just remove the `%n` from your `format` parameter:

```
out.format("%.3f",DecimalPointData);
```

So you can write:

```
out.format("%.3f", DecimalPointData);
out.print("\t");
out.println(OtherData);
```

Or simpler:

```
out.format("%.3f\t%.1f%n", DecimalPointData, OtherData);
```

See this running on [IdeOne](http://ideone.com/X23lUt).

Comment: Doesn't help, then my data in the file ends up looking like this: 

-1.075 0.0-1.092 0.0-1.075 , It gets printed row wise instead of column wise

Comment: Edited my answer for the sake of clarity.